# How many ways are there to sit 4 people from a group of 10 people around a circular table where two sittings are considered

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science, boolean-algebra

**How many ways are there to sit 4 people from a group of 10 people around a
circular table where two sittings are considered the same when everyone has the
same immediate left and immediate right neighbor?**

Wouldn't the answer just be $4*10 = 40$? or would it be $4! = 24$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to count how many ways you can choose $4$ people from $10$:

That is exactly $\frac{10!}{4!*(10-4)!}$ and then you need to multiply this with $3!$, the possibilities to sit in a circle for that $4$ people, since for $n$ people, the possibilties to sit around in a circle are $(n-1)!$

The final answer: $3! * \frac{10!}{4!*(10-4)!} = 1260$.

Comment: I think the answer should be $1260/2$. Because here the CW and ACW arrangements are considered as the same.

Answer (score 1):

First choose $4$ of the $10$ people to be seated. [$10\choose 4$ ways.]

Then seat these people in the four seats.  [$4!$ ways.]

Then divide by $4$ since you overcount by a factor of $4$ due to rotations being considered the same.

Comment: are you saying that $4!/4 = 24/4 = 6$ is the solution?

Comment: You have to multiply the $6$ by the $10\choose 4$.

Answer (score 0):

First we need to count how many way you can choose 4 from 10 people: that is 10C4= 210 ways.
Seat the first person in the circular table: 1 way ( because all positions are the same!!!)
 Seat the second, the third, the forth person, we have 9*8*7 ways
The final answer: 210*9*8*7 ways

Comment: No. You are already choosed the four peoples.So the last line should be 1×3×2×1